Question about conditional probability: $P(A_1 | B) = P(A_1 | B \cap A_2)$, $A_1, A_2$ dependent events
I know how to solve the problem stated below, but admittedly don't fully understand the solution. And there exists already a question about actually solving this problem, I'll explain below the specifics of what I'm asking:
The problem:
$A_1, A_2, A_3$ are the events that the 1st, 2nd and 3rd judge vote guilty, respectively; B is the event that the accused person is guilty. We are given $P(A_i | B ) = 0.7; P(A_i | B^c ) = 0.2$ and $P(B) = 0.7$; the question asks what is the probability that the 3rd judge will vote guilty if the other two voted guilty i.e. $P(A_3|A_1 \cap A_2)$. It can be shown that those events aren't independent i.e. the probability for the 3rd judge depends on votes of the preceding judges (they vote in order).
What I don't understand:
In the solution that I have, the following appears $P(A_1 | B) = P(A_1 | B \cap A_2)$. Intuitively it doesn't make sense for the $A_1$ judge's vote to be independent of $A_2$ so that equality shouldn't hold, since we are assuming we know that they can influence the 3rd judge (those events are dependent), how can $A_2$ not influence $A_1$ (i.e. be independent of each other)?
In the solution, the question is stated formally as $P(A_3|A_1 \cap A_2)$, so it's a bit different than the RHS of the equality I have the issue with, and I guess the fact that $B$ is given makes $A_2$ obsolete, I just don't understand why.
Edit: The original wording of the problem from A First course in probability 8th edition - Sheldon Ross

A person tried by a 3-judge panel is declared guilty
if at least 2 judges cast votes of guilty. Suppose
that when the defendant is in fact guilty, each
judge will independently vote guilty with probability .7, whereas when the defendant is in fact
innocent, this probability drops to .2. If 70 percent of defendants are guilty, compute the conditional probability that judge number 3 votes guilty
given that
(a) judges 1 and 2 vote guilty

The context in which the equality in question appears is the following equality, we needed $P(A_2 | A_1)$ to solve the problem, so we used the law of total probability $$P(A_2 | A_1) = P(A_2 | A_1, B) P(B|A_1) + P(A_2 | A_1, B^C) P(B^C|A_1)$$ Please note that here $A_1$ is actually given and not $A_2$ as in my original question above, I thought it wouldn't make a difference.

A very interesting question - intuitively, your confusion makes sense but the notion of independent is itself an oddity sometimes, not always meaning the same mathematically as linguistically... I will ponder. Just out of curiosity, where (book, competition paper etc) did this come from?

@RedFive thanks. the question is from First course in Probability-Sheldon Ross, numbered 3.89 I believe. btw, I have the lecture recording, and some students asked about this and the professor just said “but we are already given B so it’s the same”, so I thought I’m missing something obvious. perhaps I omitted an important fact, I didn’t think it would matter, but: the RHS was a factor(multiplied with P(B|A2)) of two summands (the other summand just being the B^c version) which summed up to P(A1|A2) using law of total probability. I will add/write up that nicely tomorrow when I wake up

I'm working it through now (daytime in Australia...) and will post an answer if I get anywhere.

There are some details implied but not stated by the wording in the question. I assume it's intended that if $B$, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent, and if not $B$, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent. Under these conditions and the stated probabilities, when $B$ is not known $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not independent. It doesn't mean either is influencing the other; rather, they're mutually influenced by evidence correlating to $B$ or not $B$.

Let's think about the decisions of just the two judges in a causal relationship with the innocence (or lack thereof) of the defendant,
$$A_1\longleftarrow B\longrightarrow A_2$$
This is a simple causal model called an A junction. The interpretation of this model is that the guilt or innocence of the defendant has a causal effect on the decisions of the two judges.
Importantly, constructing a causal model is just a fancy way of defining a specific dependency structure between random variables. In the case of an A junction, it is the following conditional independence,
$$P(A_1|B)=P(A_1|B,A_2)$$
We can interpret this as saying that in the absence of knowledge about $B$, knowing $A_2$ should have some impact on our knowledge about $A_1$, and vice versa. However, if $B$ is known, then since the judges deliberate separately, there is no longer any extra information to be gained about $A_1$ from knowledge of $A_2$.
Finally, from the above description it should be clear why this conditional independence does not imply full independence between $A_1$ and $A_2$, and why dependence between $A_1$ and $A_2$ is not actually contingent on anything to do with $A_3$.

thanks for the explanation. I included the original wording of the problem in my question. I still don't know how could I've realized this myself with the given information in the problem. if you encountered this problem yourself, how would you arrive at the conclusion that their dependency structure is like what you explained, and is there a situation where my intuition would be correct, i.e. how would you change the question so that my intuition is correct, or is it never correct?

@powerline The dependency structure between the judges, i.e. their conditional independence with respect to B, can be arrived at by reading the description of the problem and then thinking through its logical implications. My intent with the answer I gave was to provide a bit more detail on how one would go about doing this in a principled manner.

@powerline In your original question, you incorrectly state that $P(A_1|B)=P(A_1|B,A_2)$ implies full independence between $A_1$ and $A_2$, which as I explained in my answer is incorrect. This relation implies conditional independence between $A_1$ and $A_2$ (given B). If you wanted to modify the question so that the judges are not even conditionally independent, then this would mean that the judges deliberate together in some fashion, so that each judge makes his or her ruling based in part on what the rulings of the other two judges are.

I understand, thanks. I'll be happy to accept your answer if you can give me some hints that would help me to effectively "think through the logical implications" and eventually arrive at the fact that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are conditionally independent given $B$

If you think it's reasonably straightforward to arrive at the conditional independence, you can also just say that, I'll still accept it

@powerline the exact thought process is given in the answer. Think of the relationship between rain, wet streets and umbrellas. If you see wet streets, then it's more likely that you will see people with umbrellas. But if you already looked outside and saw whether or not it's raining, then seeing wet streets isn't going to affect your estimate of the probability of seeing people with umbrellas. Umbrellas do not cause wet streets, and wet streets do not cause umbrellas, nevertheless, in the absence of knowledge about the weather, they are dependent, or equivalently, conditionally independent.
